# Wagtail, StreamField renders admin text editor labels in the template

Tags: html, wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I've got a snippet which has an HTML editor.

```
@register_snippet
class GalleryCategory(models.Model):
    text_links = StreamField(
        [('text', DemoStreamBlock())],
        null=True,
        blank=True)
    panels = [
        StreamFieldPanel('text_links'),
    ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

When I create an instance from this snippet I am rendering it in the template like this:

```
<strong>
     {% include_block category.text_links %}
</strong>
```

However, this outputs:

```
 <strong>
    <div class="block-text">
     <div class="block-aligned_html"><dl>
      <dt>html</dt>
      <dd>Visit our <a href="/some page/" target="_blank">Facebook page</a> for more albums</dd>
      <dt>alignment</dt>
      <dd>normal</dd>
      </dl>
     </div>
    </div>
 </strong>
```

Where **html**, **alignment** and **normal** are labels in the text editor.

[image: This is the admin page editor]

[image: This is the rendered template]

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is the default front-end HTML representation of a `StructBlock`. To override this, you should set a `template` property on the `StructBlock` definition, as described at: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/topics/streamfield.html#template-rendering

Comment: I can't wrap my head around this. When I add class AlignedHTMLBlock(StructBlock):
    html = RawHTMLBlock()

    class Meta:
        icon = "user"
        template = 'cms/gallery.html' I am getting TypeError: 'class Meta' got invalid attribute(s): template

Comment: I also tried form_template since I am using version: 1.13.1 - it crashes with Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 
'request'